# Getting error <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named modules.facebook

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I have to develop web2py app and have to use Facebook sdk in that. I have downloaded facebook sdk zip folder to my windows pc and extarct it and uploaded facebook.py module to my web2py application and using statement "from applications.modules.facebook import * " in controller/default.py and when i run the application its giving below error:

No module named modules.facebook.

when i browse to application directory, I found facebook.py inside modules folder so not able to find what is the problem.

Please guide me to resolve it.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every directory in a module's path up to the module's root package [should contain an `__init__.py` file](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages). My guess is that your `applications/modules/` directory is missing one.

Comment: Additionally, you should check if applications/modules/ is in your PYTHONPATH

Comment: applications/modules/ directory is available and it is having following files: .___init__.py,._facebook.py,__init__.py,__init__.pyc,facebook.py.  but when i opened _init_.py file, it is empty so do i need to add something here?

Comment: An empty __init__.py is fine, the file just needs to exist.  That's part of the Python package convention.

Answer (score 0):

What is the folder structure of the facebook sdk? If it `facebook/` and `facebook/__init__.py` is a file within it, then you can import it using `import facebook` or `from facebook import *` from the directory where you have facebook folder. If you are importing it from within modules, then make sure that you have placed the facebook package in the modules directory of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention your directory name in environmental variable PYTHONPATH so that it will locate your directory.

Hopes this will help you :)